# find + get $? output diff then 0 when find not match the word

Tags: find

when I perform

```
  find /tmp  -name something
```

find command not find the something word under /tmp

```
  echo $?

  I get $?=0
```

it's OK

but how to enable Exit status diff then 0 when find command not find the something word?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/225798/find-command-enable-exit-status-to-be-diff-then-0-when-not-match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns 0 if it runs successfully and non-zero if there are errors. It does not set the exit code based on whether anything was found. You will need to do something like this:

```
files=$(find /tmp  -name something)
if [[ -n "$files" ]]
then
    echo "files were found"
fi
```

It's more likely, however, that you want to do something with the filenames. You can process them in a loop:

```
find /tmp  -name something | while read -r filename
do
    echo "found: $filename
done
```

or

```
while read -r filename
do
    echo "found: $filename
done < <(find /tmp  -name something)
```

If nothing is found then the loop will exit without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is the most concise and direct method:

```
test "`find /tmp/ -name something -print -quit 2>/dev/null`"
```

Comment: This will only work if there's not more than a single match. Double quotes around the backticks should overcome this.

Comment: Also, I accidentally omitted `-print -quit`.